# No Line found error but I don't see how?

Tags: java

Pretty much I'm trying to write a program that counts the words in a text file  AND count how many lines as well but I keep getting the no line error.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class input {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    String name;
    int lineCount = 0;
    int wordCount = 0;
    File input = new File("C:\\Users\\Ceri\\workspace1\\inputoutput\\src\\inputoutput\\lab1task3.txt");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(input);

    while(in.hasNextLine()){
        while(in.hasNext()){
            wordCount++;
            in.next();
        }
        lineCount++;
        in.nextLine();
    }

    System.out.println(lineCount);
    System.out.println(wordCount);
    in.close();


}

}
```

The issue lays withing the while(in.hasnextline()) loop.

Comment: Please provide the stacktrace of this code.

Answer (score 1):

That is because your inner while loop exhasts all the input characters from your scanner. `in.hasNext()` does not stop at new line characters.

Comment: I forgot to add that I need to count the lines as well.

Comment: I got that.. Was just telling you what was causing `no line` error. There are multiple ways of counting both words and lines. One of the solutions is below given by @Elizion. May not be the most efficient but gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

You are incorrectly implementing `hasNextLine()` and `hasNext()` such that you have read through all the tokens in your `scanner` within your inner `while`.
 An easier way to read every word and line would be to implement something like this:

```
int words = 0;
 int lines = 0;

   while(in.hasNextLine())  {
        lines++;
        String line = in.nextLine()
        words += new StringTokenizer(line, " ,").countTokens();
    }
```

Comment: This works.. kind of, the value of words should be 13 where as when I run it is 14.

Comment: @ceriWestcott You'll have to change your word separators accordingly then! This is the shortest way that I know how to implement it.(Not saying it is legitimately the best way however)

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
while(in.hasNextLine())
{
    Scanner ins=new Scanner(in.nextLine());
    while(ins.hasNext())
    {
       wordCount++;
       ins.next();
    }
    lineCount++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are reaching end of the file while looping through the inner loop. Once, it reaches the end of file, it will come out of inner loop. `lineCount` will be incremented and then, `in.nextLine()` will be executed. Buffer for Scanner's object is not having any value inside of it, hence you are getting this result.

Try this:

```
while(in.hasNextLine()){
    String line = in.nextLine();
    lineCount++;
    String[] words = line.split(" ");
    wordCount += words.length;
}
```